# returning a typedef struct in a method in C

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to create a struct that holds parsing information and i want to create a method that returns the stuct with the data filled in. This is what I have so far but I am getting an error saying Parser.c:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘parseString’

Parser.h

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct 
    {
       char* myArguments;
       char* myProgramName;
           int myNumArguments;

    }ParserData;


    ParserData parseString(int argc, char** argv);
```

Parser.c

```
    #include "Parser.h"

    ParserData parseString(int argc, char **argv)
    {
         ParserData tempData;

         tempData.myNumArguments = argc;

         return tempData; 
    }
```

Mish.h

```
    #include "Parser.h"

    ParserData myParserData;
```

Mish.c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include "Mish.h"

   #define MAXLINE 1024


   int main(int argc, char *argv[], char **environ)
   {
       char buf[MAXLINE];
       pid_t pid;
           int status;

       printf("mish>"); //Print shell

       myParserData = parseString(argc, argv);

       while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) 
       {
       buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0; /* replace newline with null */

       if ( (pid = fork()) < 0)
       {
          printf("fork error");
       }
       else if (pid == 0) /* child */
       { 
          execlp(buf, argv[1], (char *) 0);
          printf("couldn't execute: %s", buf);
          return(127);
       }

       /* parent */
       if ( (pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0)
       {
          printf("waitpid error");  
          printf("%% ");
       }

       }

  return(0);
    }
```

Comment: @raina77ow since 1977 approximately.

Comment: Damn, it was a bit cold in that cryogenic camera. )

Comment: I tried to compile your code and it works fine on my side

Comment: There seems to be no error in this code. Could you tell us what else you have?

Comment: Have you included the whole header/source files?

Comment: Im trying to compile with the following command. Note that I have 2 other 2 source files Mish.c and Mish .h but Im not conerned aobut those at the moment.

gcc -o mish Parser.c Mish.c

Comment: even after just doing

gcc -o mish Parser.c

it dosent work

Comment: Are you including int main in your original code?

Comment: yea int main is in Mish.c and in mish.h I have basicly #include "Parser.h" but even with just compiling Parser.c dosent work.

Comment: I copied everything, ran `gcc -o mish Parser.c Mish.c` and... it compiles

Comment: I, too, copied all the files and compiled them — and no error.

Comment: gcc -o mish Parser.c Mish.c ERROR: Parser.c:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘parseString’

Comment: One more for the "compiles without a problem" team.

Comment: Just an idea - do you have a newline at the end of parser.h?

Comment: Add me to the "compiles without a problem" friend-list. Running... now *thats* a different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was not a problem with code but a problem with the files. I noticed the .h files had Mish.h.gch and Parser.h.gch. I deleted the .h's and the .h.gch and recreated the .h files and then compiled with "gcc -o mish Parser.c Mish.c" and it compiled successfully. My guess is that it was a problem with the new code not being updated properly...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach (`main.c`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char* myArguments;
    char* myProgramName;
    int myNumArguments;
} ParserData;

ParserData * parseString(int argc, char** argv);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ParserData *foo = NULL;

    foo = parseString(argc, (char **)argv);
    if (foo) {
        fprintf(stderr, "myNumArguments: %d\n", foo->myNumArguments);
        free(foo);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}

ParserData *
parseString(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ParserData *tempData;

    tempData = malloc(sizeof(ParserData));
    tempData->myNumArguments = argc;

    return tempData;
}
```

To compile:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -o foo
```

To run:

```
$ ./foo 
myNumArguments: 1
$ ./foo bar
myNumArguments: 2
```

This leaves out a lot of error checking code and memory management for the two `char *` in the structure. Hopefully it will help you figure out what to split into header and implementation files.

Comment: unfortunatly that would require me to rework the way i have Mish.c and Mish.h set up. I also tried making the parsestring method return a pointer to a ParseData struct but that still gave me the same error.

Comment: Perhaps your best bet is to post all the code. Everything. Then it can be reviewed to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Please also post your compilation command and the full error text that results.

Comment: gcc -o mish Parser.c Mish.c
ERROR:
Parser.c:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘parseString’